# Angular-ui-router:load one of the child state as default from parent abstract state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My app uses Angularjs-ui-router to switch between different modules.i have 2 child states from parent state. i need to load 'home.search' state as default and 'home.fileupload' on button click,but currently 'home.fileupload' state loads tabs.html too.

is there way on page entry load default state as 'home.search' state and on button click load 'home.fileupload' state from parent abstract state(home.html)???

**routes.js**

```
  .state('home', {
          abstract: true, 
          templateUrl: 'scripts/home.html'
   })

  .state('home.search', {
       url: '/summary',
       views: {               
          'search': 
          {
                    templateUrl: "scripts/home/search.html"
          },
          'summary': 
          {
                    templateUrl: "scripts/home/summary.html"
          }
      }
   })
  .state('home.fileupload', {
      url: '/fileupload',
      views: {               
       'upload': 
          {
                    templateUrl: "scripts/home/upload.html"
          }
       }
  })
```

**home.html**

```
 <button type="button" ng-click="goToState('home.search')">Search</button>
 <button type="button" ng-click="goToState('home.fileupload')">fileUpload</button>
 <div ng-include="'scripts/home/tabs.html'"></div>
```

**tabs.html**

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">    
  <div ui-view="summary"></div>   
  <div ui-view="search"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link to working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/7xiXm41zIlncWRcNBRT8?p=preview). I've made few changes, to make it more `ui-router` like.

Firstly we have to move controller definition from `<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">` into state definition:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'scripts/home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl', // here we put together template and controller
  })

.state('home.search', {
  url: '/summary',
  views: {
    'search': {
      templateUrl: "scripts/home/search.html",
      controller: 'SearchCtrl', // here as well
    },
    'summary': {
      templateUrl: "scripts/home/summary.html",
      controller: 'SummaryCtrl', // here also
    }
  }
})
...
```

also, part of the template for abstract state `home` should be `<div ui-view="upload"></div>`, as a placeholder for file upload state.

And this is the start up:

```
.config(['$urlRouterProvider',
    function($urlRouterProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/summary');
    }
 ]);
```

Check all that in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7xiXm41zIlncWRcNBRT8?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use module.run() method to set the default route. This is how you do it:

```
testModule = angular.module('ModuleName', []);
testModule.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
$state.go('statename');
}]);
```

Run block is executed when the app boots. Read about run blocks if you have any confusion: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module